# Scaling an \input within a subfigure

Tags: floats, input

I'm including latex files with \input within a subfigure environment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{linegoal}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        \scalebox{.4}{\input{figures/steps/step-001.tex}}
        \caption{Step 1 of the example run}
        \label{step1er}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        \scalebox{.4}{\input{figures/steps/step-002.tex}}
        \caption{Step 2 of the example run}
        \label{step2er}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But they simply refuse to scale, and the output is completely messed up. The right figure stretches even more vertically.

Here is what it looks like in the PDF: [image: http://imgur.com/48JqT5N]

Comment: What is in `step-001.tex`?

Comment: It's an output of my ansicolor2latex script: https://dpaste.de/sbO1

Comment: The last `\end{subfigure}` should be `\end{figure}`, when I fix that it works fine.

Comment: Actually that was merely a typo in the simplification of my 6-way subfigure. :( I will post the entire code. Also, here is `step-002.tex` just for reference: https://dpaste.de/Fv2b

Comment: `\scalebox` or `\resizebox`? The syntax is wrong for the former, correct for the latter (see `graphicx` manual). `\scalebox{.5}{\input{..}}`  or `\resizebox{.5\linewidth}{!}{\input{..}}`. Edit: It's always best if you create complete examples, starting with `\documentclass`, including the necessary packages and definitions (but only the necessary ones) ending with `\end{document}`, so that we can just copy-paste and compile the whole thing.

Comment: Sorry, I tried many variants, and got them a bit mixed up. However `\scalebox` with the  correct syntax scales the left figure properly and the right figure wrong, while resizebox depending on the factor of linewidth stretches the figure over the whole page. I will try to post a minimal example soon.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I've added the repro code. The first time I run `pdflatex`, the result looks kinda ok, but gets messed up when I run `pdflatex` again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is I think quite simply that the `\parbox` in your `step`-files is too narrow to fit the text, so it overflows out of the parbox, and hence out of the `\fcolorbox`. If you use a large enough width, in this specific case `1.5\linewidth` seems to fit well, the result is better:

[image]

I'm not entirely sure why the second box is that narrow, but I suppose it has to do with `linegoal`, and how the remainder of the line in question is calculated.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{linegoal}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{stuff.tex}
\texttt{\fcolorbox{Blue}{Black}{\parbox[t]{1.5\linewidth}{% <-- note that the width has changed here
\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}|\color[HTML]{DCDCCC}A0\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}|\color[HTML]{DCDCCC}A0\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}|\color[HTML]{DCDCCC}A0\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}|\color[HTML]{DCDCCC}A0\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}|\color[HTML]{DCDCCC}A0\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}|\color[HTML]{DCDCCC}A5\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}|\color[HTML]{DCDCCC}A5\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}|\color[HTML]{DCDCCC}A5\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}|\color[HTML]{DCDCCC}A5\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}|\color[HTML]{DCDCCC}A5\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}|\color[HTML]{DCDCCC}AA\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}|\color[HTML]{DCDCCC}AA\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}|\color[HTML]{DCDCCC}AA\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}|\color[HTML]{DCDCCC}AA\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}|\color[HTML]{DCDCCC}AA\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}|\color[HTML]{DCDCCC}AF\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}|\\
\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}|\color[HTML]{DCDCCC}F0\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}|\color[HTML]{DCDCCC}F0\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}|\color[HTML]{DCDCCC}F0\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}|\color[HTML]{DCDCCC}F0\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}|\color[HTML]{DCDCCC}F0\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}|\color[HTML]{DCDCCC}F5\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}|\color[HTML]{DCDCCC}F5\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}|\color[HTML]{DCDCCC}F5\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}|\color[HTML]{DCDCCC}F5\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}|\color[HTML]{DCDCCC}F5\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}|\color[HTML]{DCDCCC}FA\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}|\color[HTML]{DCDCCC}FA\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}|\color[HTML]{DCDCCC}FA\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}|\color[HTML]{DCDCCC}FA\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}|\color[HTML]{DCDCCC}FA\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}|\color[HTML]{DCDCCC}FF\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}|\\
\color[HTML]{DCDCCC}\\
Status:\\
 \color[HTML]{F0E68C}Initializing}}}
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \resizebox{.95\linewidth}{!}{\input{stuff}}
        \caption{Step 1 of the example run}
        \label{step1er}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \scalebox{.4}{\input{stuff}}
        \caption{Step 2 of the example run}
        \label{step2er}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. The reason the right one is thinner in your example is because you're using `\scalebox{.4}` rather than `\resizebox{.95\linewidth}{!}` as with the left figure. :)

Comment: @knuth_whitebear No, that's not what I meant. If you look at your image in the question, the black box on the right is just a few millimeters wide. I am well aware that I set the widths in my example differently for the the two subfigures.